# Parsing XML in Rockwell FTPC

Tags: xml, parsing

I m working on Rockwell FTPC... I have an xml, and I want to parse it get the data out of it.

Here is my xml:

```
<part>
<partlist>part001</partlist>
<partlist>part002</partlist>
<partlist>part003</partlist>
</part>
```

I m writing following code to get the data.

```
    filePath = openFileDialog()
doc=readDocument(filePath)
node=selectSingleNode( doc,"/PartList")
nodeList = selectNodeList( node, "Part")
nodePartNo=selectNodeList(doc,".//PARTNO")
// println(nodePartNo.value.toString())
// println(nodeList.item(0).pop())
println("The node list length is: " +nodeList.getLength())
```

help me in retreiving node values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please use getTextContent() as item(i).getTextContent()

this should solve the problem